# Annotation is selected works 1 to 2 times when map region change to Center pin and not work all times

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I have problem in Annotation View When i tap First time in Annotation it callout perfect and set Annotation in Center of MapView but after i change Region and Again i click on Annotation it just center on mapview but now callout bubble. Please check below DidselectAnnotationView method is 
there any problem.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
 {

    region.center.latitude =  view.annotation.coordinate.latitude ;
    region.center.longitude = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude;

   CLLocationCoordinate2D pointLocation =
  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,     
  view.annotation.coordinate.longitude);
  [self.mapViewAlert setCenterCoordinate:pointLocation animated:TRUE];

   [(MKMapView*)self.mapViewAlert selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];

  }
```

Comment: Rephrasing your question: You have a region set, and add an annotation. Tapping the annotation works correctly. However if you change the region and then click on the same annotation it does not show the callout bubble as you expect. Is that accurate? Is this with Apple Maps (==iOS 6), or not (<=iOS 5) or both?

Comment: this is apple map in ios 5.  this is same for both ios 6 and ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude =  view.annotation.coordinate.latitude ;
region.center.longitude = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude;

region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05f;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05f;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```